# WAMP 2.2 Localhost Call to undefined function curl_init()

Tags: php, curl, localhost, wamp

I am using wamp 2.2 with php 5.3.13 and Apache 2.2.22 and I am getting this error on my localhost:

`Call to undefined function curl_init()`

I removed `;` from `extension=php_curl.dll` 
My `extension_dir = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/ext/"` is correct
I have restarted my wamp server and even download the php_curl.dll from the following URL http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/

and I am still getting this error...anyone got any ideas?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the php_curl extension is selected in your Wamp PHP extension options.

Edit to make the answer clear: There are two php_curl.dll files to be found on the website linked to in the question:
http://www.mediafire.com/file/0hm40owj08y68p7/php_curl-5.3.13-nts-VC9-x64.zip
and
http://www.mediafire.com/file/qwgdzgccthzwc15/php_curl-5.3.13-VC9-x64.zip

Looks like only one of them worked for the OP.

Comment: Yes it is selected in my wamp php extension options.

Comment: If you do a `phpinfo()`, is the curl extension showing up? Any errors in the Apache error log when you do a restart?

Comment: I get these errors `[Fri Aug 23 17:06:39 2013] [notice] Parent: Created child process 5676
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/ext/php_curl.dll' - The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
<br />`

Comment: I searched for curl in my phpinfo and nothing was there :(

Comment: There are two php_curl.dll's for download on the page you linked to - http://www.mediafire.com/file/0hm40owj08y68p7/php_curl-5.3.13-nts-VC9-x64.zip and http://www.mediafire.com/file/qwgdzgccthzwc15/php_curl-5.3.13-VC9-x64.zip . Have you tried both?